# How to copy a row from existing excel sheet to a new excel sheet using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to compare two excel sheets and find if any row differs, if it does I want to copy that single row which differs from that excel to a new row in a new excel. Below is a code snippet I took from the net and tried but the problem if I  copy the 10th row of the existing excel(for example) to the first row of new excel, 1st row is properly copied in new excel but all the remaining rows from first excel are also copied to the new one. I think the problem is with the way I write to new excel [workbook.write(out)] Please help!! Thanks in advance!!

```
    public class RowCopy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("c:/input.xls"));
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    copyRow(workbook, sheet, 0, 1);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/output.xls");
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
}

private static void copyRow(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
    // Get the source / new row
    HSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    HSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
    if (newRow != null) {
        worksheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
    } else {
        newRow = worksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
    }

    // Loop through source columns to add to new row
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
        HSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        HSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
        if (oldCell == null) {
            newCell = null;
            continue;
        }

        // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
        HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        ;
        newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

        // If there is a cell comment, copy
        if (oldCell.getCellComment() != null) {
            newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
        }

        // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
        if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
            newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
        }

        // Set the cell data type
        newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

        // Set the cell data value
        switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your method `copyRow` is just method to copy from one row to another row in the same file and sheet(input.xls-Sheet1), and the output.xls is just new blank xls? that code is completely different from your explanation.

Comment: ya this is the code I took from the net, the code logic that compares the excel is different. Once I compare and find the difference I will get that row id and send it as the parameter to this function "CopyRow". But my doubt is, I want to write only a  particular row only from input.xls to the new excel output.xls(yes, it is a new blank xls) but with code other rows of inout.xls is also being copied to new excel.. how do I do that?(If input.xls has 10 rows, all that are also copied to new file output.xls). Hope I'm clear

Comment: post your other code. and as i mentioned before `copyRow` is just method to copy from one row to another row in the same file and same sheet, its not what you need right(creating new xls)?

Comment: @Angga: Thanks for the response. Sorry I don't have that other code with me that's the problem. Okay, let me put it this way, forget about the compare excel part. How to alter this `copyRow` method so that I can copy one row to another row in a new excel file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the `copyRow` method, add parameter `HSSFSheet resultSheet` then modify `newRow` variable in the method to get that from `resultSheet` like this

```
private static void copyRow(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet worksheet, HSSFSheet resultSheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
    // Get the source / new row
    HSSFRow newRow = resultSheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    HSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);
```

take that resultSheet from your destination "output.xls"

Comment: Thanks a ton @Angga.. That works! I am facing another difficulty, in this `copyRow` method I don't want to copy the style from the input sheet, so I removed the clone part and added foreground color, the color is applying properly to the new row but color is not filling over the cells with contents in the new row. Except the cells with  content other cells in the new row are filled with foreground color. But I want to color the entire row, how to do that? It would be really useful if you can help with this too. My guess is its first filling up the color and then copying the values from input

Comment: please mark it as accepted answer if my answer work, and make different question when you meet different problem. CZ posting code in a comment will be dificult you know :D but maybe add this to your style will help `style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);`

Comment: it is possible to copy row from one workbook to another workbook ?

Answer (score 3):

Copy from one sheet to another

```
public static void copyFromSourceToDestinationRow(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sourceWorksheet, int sourceRowNum, XSSFSheet destinationWorksheet, int destinationRowNum) {
        // Get the source / new row
        XSSFRow sourceRow = sourceWorksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);
        XSSFRow newRow = destinationWorksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
        // Loop through source columns to add to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
            XSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
            XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);
            // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
            if (oldCell == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

            // If there is a cell comment, copy
            if (oldCell.getCellComment() != null) {
                newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
            }

            // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
            if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
                newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
            }

            // Set the cell data type
            newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellTypeEnum());

            // Set the cell data value
            switch (oldCell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case BLANK:// Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case FORMULA:
                newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case STRING:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        // If there are are any merged regions in the source row, copy to new row
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceWorksheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
            CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = sourceWorksheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            if (cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow() == sourceRow.getRowNum()) {
                CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.getRowNum(),
                        (newRow.getRowNum() + (cellRangeAddress.getLastRow() - cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow())),
                        cellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn(), cellRangeAddress.getLastColumn());
                destinationWorksheet.addMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
            }
        }
    }
```

Jar file
=-------

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
```